# Como excluir um elemento de um vetor em Java

Tags: java

Estou com problema no `case` *5*, onde eu tenho que excluir os elementos do vetor, alguém pode ajudar? estou começando a programar agora.

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class Gere {

    public static void main (String [] arg) {


    Professor Pr[];
    Pr = new Professor [20];

  int Matri = 0;
  int Cont = -1;
  int  Menu = 0;    


 do {  Menu = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n1 = Inserir. \n2 = Imprimir. \n3 = Buscar por matricula. \n4 = Buscar  por nome. \n5 = Excluir. \n6 = Sair."));

        switch (Menu) {


    case 1: {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"O menu escolhido foi 1 = Inserir.");    

        Cont ++;

      Pr[Cont] = new Professor();           
      Pr[Cont].setMatricula(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe a Matricula")));
      Pr[Cont].setNome(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o Nome"));
      Pr[Cont].setSalario(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o Salario")));
      Pr[Cont].setMateria(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe a Materia"));

    break;
    }   

case 2: {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"O menu escolhido foi 2 = Imprimir.");       

    for (int i = 0; i <=Cont; i++) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\n Matricula:" + Pr[i].getMatricula() + 
                                        "\n Nome:" + Pr[i].getNome() + 
                                        "\n Salario:"  + Pr[i].getSalario() +
                                        "\n Materia:" + Pr[i].getMateria() ); 

                                        }

 break; 

 }      

case 3: {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"O menu escolhido foi 3 = Buscar por matricula.");   

    Matri = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n Digite a matricula"));


    for ( int e =0; e !=    Matri;  e++) {

    if (Matri == Pr[e].getMatricula() ) {


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\n Matricula:" + Pr[e].getMatricula() + 
                                        "\n Nome:" + Pr[e].getNome() + 
                                        "\n Salario:"  + Pr[e].getSalario() +
                                        "\n Materia:" + Pr[e].getMateria() ); 
    }   
    }   
    break;  
    }       


case 4: {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"O menu escolhido foi 4 = Buscar  por Nome.");   

    String Nom = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n Digite o Nome");

    for ( int o=0; o <Cont ; o++) {

    if (Nom.equals(Pr[o].getNome()) ) {


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\n Matricula:" + Pr[o].getMatricula() + 
                                        "\n Nome:" + Pr[o].getNome() + 
                                        "\n Salario:"  + Pr[o].getSalario() +
                                        "\n Materia:" + Pr[o].getMateria() ); 

    }   
    }   
    break;  
    }       

case 5: {
    int remover=0;
    int Matri2 =0;  
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"O menu escolhido foi 5 = Excluir.");    

    Matri2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n Digite a matricula"));

    for ( int u=0; u < Matri ; u++) {

    if (Matri2 == remover(Pr[u].getMatricula()) ) {

    }
    }

    break;  
    }           

    }

    } while (Menu != 6);    


    }

}
```

Comment: Ao invés de usar vetor, por que você não utiliza um `List`. É muito mais fácil de manipular objetos na mesma, especialmente quando se fala de remoção

Comment: Vai que ele quer entender ainda o funcionamento de vetores...

Answer (score 2):

- **A resposta rápida é:**

Você não pode remover elementos de um vetor. Vetores tem tamanhos definidos portanto não há como alterar seu tamanho, o que você pode fazer é deixa a posição `x` como nula, como segue no exemplo:

```
Integer[] andaresPredio = new Integer[10];
// preenchendo
andaresPredio [1] = 54;
// apagando valor
andaresPredio [1] = null;
```

Ou você pode usar `ArrayList`, não sei qual o seu nível de JAVA por isso segue abaixo várias formas de se usar o `ArrayList` e escolha a melhor para você:

```
    /** forma 1 */
    List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numeros.add(15);
    numeros.add(32);
    // removendo
    numeros.remove(1);

    /** forma 2 */
    List numeros2 = new ArrayList();
    numeros2.add(15);
    numeros2.add(32);
    // removendo
    numeros2.remove(1);

    /** forma 3 */
    ArrayList numeros3 = new ArrayList();
    numeros3.add(15);
    numeros3.add(32);
    // removendo
    numeros3.remove(1);

    /** forma 4 */
    ArrayList<Integer> numeros4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numeros4.add(15);
    numeros4.add(32);
    // removendo
    numeros4.remove(1);
```

Comment: diferença de ArrayLis para List é qual?

Comment: `List` é uma interface, `ArrayList` é uma classe que implementa essa interface, se os métodos da interface já resolvem o que você precisa é bom usar a interface na assinatura da variável, mas isso é convenção, na prática os dois resolvem